# Unity Get back VR input

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, gyroscope, virtual-reality

I am working on unity and I am trying to get the best gyroscope input possible from my mobile.

I find out that the VR option of Unity bring a nice result, and would like to only get back the result, without having to use a double VR camera.

Do you know how to do such things ?

Thanks all !

Comment: Why not use [Gyroscope](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gyroscope.html) input?

Comment: This Script might be useful too: [https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/sharing-gyroscope-controlled-camera-on-iphone-4.98828/#post-849438](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/sharing-gyroscope-controlled-camera-on-iphone-4.98828/#post-849438)

Comment: Fenixrw, Input.gyro.attitude is what I am using right now, but the result is far worst than the result I can see using VR

Comment: It might be possible to set a VR cam to render to a texture and use the camera rotation as the gyro input only, but it is a workaround, not a good practice.

Comment: I am searching into the Unity code.
First, I tought I could have some clues using the Google Cardboard API, but it leads that at runtime it uses UnityEngine.VR.InputTracking.GetLocalRotation(VRNode.Head) only to have feedback from Unity.

So I find the InputTracking.GetLocalRotation from here https://github.com/MattRix/UnityDecompiled/blob/master/UnityEngine/UnityEngine.VR/InputTracking.cs

But I am now struggled with the 
INTERNAL_CALL_GetLocalRotation

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally managed to something terrible.

I download the Cardboard API 0.5
Then, I use a CardboardMain prefab, and set the Distortion correction to None
I create after one update (yield return null) a new camera to replace to deactivated one from Cardboard API
I can retrieve the gyroscope modification by following the Head from the CardboardMain prefab

Good luck, tell me if you find better !

Ps : I am using this technic in this app : http://lightgunmouse.com/